# Check if iFrame is loaded. ONE time. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, load

I know there is many of possiblites when it comes to check if an iFrame content has been loaded. Although, is there anyway to limit it?

Example, if I have an iframe, and I need to check if everything has loaded, I can use the load() function. Although, if I click a NEW link inside the iframe, it will run the load() function again.

What I wish to know, is there any way to do, so jquery only checks the FIRST time the iFrame content has been loaded?

I have tried everything, nothing works.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use jquery .[one](http://api.jquery.com/one/), it does the unbind work for you.

```
$('#iframe').one('load', function() {


});
```

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apcWJ/).

Comment: there is a syntax error in the example: ,(function should not have the bracket: ,function

Answer (score 8):

You can unset the load callback again once it gets called.

```
$('#iframe').load(function() {

  // do things which are awesome

  $('#iframe').unbind('load');

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did the trick. I wasn't aware that you could unbind the functions.

Comment: you should unbind *first* if you really want it to have a high likelyhood of getting called only once